# Boost.Python tries to link against python27.lib using Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, boost-python

I'm trying to build boost python using Python 3.2. I'm linking against python32.lib and libboost_python3-vc110-mt-gd-1_52.lib. I also definied BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to disable boost's auto link feature.

Still I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
```

How to tell boost to use Python 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple Python installations on your computer?

You probably have to create a `user-config.jam` file with content like this:

```
using python : 3.2 : C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe ;
```

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#configuring-boost-build