# Boost.Python tries to link Python 2.7 even though Python 3.6 is installed

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

I posted about this problem a few days ago (now deleted), but have since gotten closer to a solution and therefore, I think, better able to ask a constructive question.

I am trying to use Boost.Python in Visual Studio to build a basic C++ 'hello world' function as a .pyd file; my process is as follows:

- Create new empty project
- Set target extension to .pyd and configuration type to .dll
- Include and link necessary Python folders per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/cpp-and-python) under the section "Create the core C++ project"
- Import VS2017 Boost.Python3 package via package manager console (PM> Install-Package boost_python3-vc141 -Version 1.65.1)

Then I copy a basic 'hello world' function and wrapper from [this website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html):

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

However, upon attempting to build the solution, I receive the error, "LNK1104 cannot open file 'python27.lib'" I think that my problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188809/boost-python-tries-to-link-against-python27-lib-using-visual-c), but I tried creating a 'user-config.jam' file in my home directory:

```
import toolset : using ;
using python : 3.6 : C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe ;
```

And I continue to receive the same error message.

**How do I force Boost.Python3 to use Python 3.6 instead of the 'default' Python 2.7?**

Comment: Keep in mind that Python2 and Python3 code is not always compatible. Meaning; not all Python2 code is valid Python3 and vice versa. They bumped that version number for a reason.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks for the clarification, but that's exactly the problem: I'm using Boost.Python3 instead of Boost.Python (2) to avoid issues with legacy code, but Boost insists on trying to find the Python2 LIB file anyway. I have nothing related to Python2 installed on my machine.